# What does this statement mean "Cypress commands do not return their subjects, they yield them"?

Tags: javascript, testing, frontend, cypress

I'm learning about Cypress.io and came across this statement in their official site [Cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Subject-Management)

> "Cypress commands do not return their subjects, they yield them."

What is the difference between "yield" and "return" in commands in cypress.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take yield to mean 'pay it forward', whereas return = 'pay it back'.

See [Core Concepts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Examples)

> Cypress commands are asynchronous and get queued for execution at a later time. During execution, subjects are yielded from one command to the next, and a lot of helpful Cypress code runs between each command to ensure everything is in order.

Answer (score 1):

They do not synchronously return objects like you would expect, it takes a bit of time to get used to - but once you get it, you get it.

This will not work like you expect because `cy.get` is asynchronous so myButton will not be set before you call `.click()` on it:

```
var myButton = cy.get(#myButton);
myButton.click(); //Nope!
```

Cypress commands yield objects to [Chainers](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Subject-Management) which queue up actions to perform, so you would use it like this:

```
cy.get(#myButton).click(); //Yes!
```

Or:

```
cy.get(#myButton).then(myButton => {
  // do stuff with myButton here
});
```

Some additional reading: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values